# How to find a transfer function when an \$\omega\$ is not paired with \$j\$?

Tags: bode-plot

With the standard transfer function of:

$$H(s) = \frac{N(s)}{D(s)} =  \frac{(s-z_1)(s-z_2)...(s-z_{m-1})(s-z_m)}{(s-p_1)(s-p_2)...(s-p_{n-1})(s-p_n)}$$

and defining: \$s = \sigma + j\omega\$

Can you put a transfer function into this form if you have an \$\omega\$ not multiplied by a \$j\$?

To give some context, you can run into this scenario when finding the impedance of a  capacitor using a series R,L,C model.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3u1Kz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$\hat{Z} = R + j\omega L + \frac{1}{j\omega C}$$

$$\hat{Z} = \frac{j\omega RC - \omega^2LC + 1}{j\omega C}$$

If you treat \$\omega\$ as your input variable and \$\hat{Z}\$ as your output variable, then the complex impedance can be seen as a transfer function. For the equation shown, can you put this into the pole-zero format?

---

Edit:

What I was not seeing here is that in \$s = \sigma + j\omega\$, \$\sigma==0\$ for sinusoidal inputs, as there is no real (decaying) part to the input (See [Why do we use \$s=j\omega\$ in AC analysis instead of \$s=\sigma+j\omega\$?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78638/why-do-we-use-s-j-omega-in-ac-analysis-instead-of-s-sigmaj-omega)). This means that \$s^2 = -\omega^2\$. Thus my previous equation can be changed to look like:

$$\hat{Z} = L\frac{-\omega^2 + j\omega \frac{R}{L} + \frac{1}{LC}}{j\omega}$$
$$\hat{Z} = L\frac{s^2 + s\frac{R}{L} + \frac{1}{LC}}{s}$$

See Matt L.'s answer for the rest.

Comment: The components of the transfer function without a complex term are just the real part, sigma as you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a function of \$s\$ you get for the impedance

$$Z(s)=R+sL+\frac{1}{sC}=\frac{s^2LC+RCs+1}{sC}=L\frac{s^2+\frac{R}{L}s+\frac{1}{LC}}{s}\tag{1}$$

Computing the zeros of the numerator of (1) gives

$$z_{1,2}=-\frac{R}{2L}\pm\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{4L^2}-\frac{1}{LC}}\tag{2}$$

With these zeros, the impedance (1) can be written as

$$Z(s)=L\frac{(s-z_1)(s-z_2)}{s}\tag{3}$$

From (3) it is clear that apart from the two zeros at \$s=z_1\$ and \$s=z_2\$ we have two poles at \$s=0\$ and \$s\rightarrow\infty\$, which makes sense because for DC the impedance becomes infinite due to the capacitor, and for \$\omega\rightarrow\infty\$ the impedance goes to infinity due to the inductor.